# How to apply CSS for only specific area?

Tags: html, css

I have a html page like below and `dynamicContentDiv` is loading from database. Some contents have styles and this styles also affects other elements outside of `dynamicContentDiv`. Is there any way to prevent this effect?

```
<body>
    ....
    <div id="dynamicContentDiv">
       ....
       <style>
           <!-- Some CSS Here -->
       </style>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: update selector `#dynamicContentDiv <your_selector>{.....}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the selectors with`#dynamicContentDiv` to select within the div only.

```
#dynamicContentDiv <your_selector> {
  /*... style properties ....*/
}
```

Refer : [Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

---

Alternately you can load the content into an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), the style inside it doesn't effect on the parent page.

Comment: I am getting dynamicContentDiv from database and of course all styles. Do I need to edit all this styles? I mean some contents has nearly 100 classes. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: @hellzone : then it's better to load these content into an iframe or update style code in backend

Answer (score 0):

Put your desired content in a div and apply your css only to it

```css
button {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inside button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="inside"><button>Inside</button></div>

<button>Out</button>

<div><button>Out</button></div>
```

Comment: I am getting dynamicContentDiv from database and of course all styles. Do I need to edit all this styles? I mean some contents has nearly 100 classes. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: you just have to apply the css by adding dynamicContentDiv at the start

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your styles to a specific `<div>` by updating the CSS selector to  with `#dynamicContentDiv`:

```
<div id="dynamicContentDiv">
   ....
   <style>
       #dynamicContentDiv{
           // div style
       }
       #dynamicContentDiv input{
           // input style
       }
       #dynamicContentDiv .someClass{
           // generic class under this div
       }
   </style>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting dynamicContentDiv from database and of course all styles. Do I need to edit all this styles? I mean some contents has nearly 100 classes. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: @hellzone Not that I can think of. You have to specify the DIV in the CSS somehow, otherwise it will effect the entire page's style.